# Find most frequent value, then count another value from results in MyQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I find the most frequent value within a table, then add up the value from those columns for outputting data?

```
player    | money
player001 | 120
player001 | 140
player002 | 100
player003 | 200
```

The end result should output something like `Player001 has 260 money` - sort of like a leaderboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your result, you don't want the most *frequent* value.  You want the highest sum per player.  That would be:

```
select player, sum(money)
from t
group by player
order by sum(money) desc
limit 1;
```

If you want a single string from this, I would recommend doing that at the application layer.  However, you could use `concat()` to format a string in the SQL itself.

Comment: Thank you for this. The code I had was close but I think I was just abit tired and couldn't figure it out.